# Python : How to set a condition to 'ignore' some code if this condition is met?

Tags: python, function, loops, input, conditional-statements

I am using Python (I think it's version 2.7)

I have a section of code here, which is part of a function that takes x_1,x_2 and x_f (same for y) as inputs and colours in corresponding pixels in an image (x_f and y_f denote the final pixels in the image, so that it is only drawing within the image bounds.

```
while x_1+k*x_2<=x_f and y_1+k*y_2<=y_f:
    pixels[x_1+k*x_2,y_2+k*y_2]=colour
    k+=1
```

The issue I have is, I require this code to take an input `x_f (or y_f) = Empty`

If `x_f=Empty`, the above piece of code should ignore the entire x section in the first line and produce an output based only on y values like this:

```
while y_1+k*y_2<=y_f:
    pixels[x_1+k*x_2,y_2+k*y_2]=colour
    k+=1
```

and visa-versa. Unfortunately, I can't work out how to get it to do this.

My attempts included:

```
if x_f is not Empty and y_f is not Empty: 
    while x_1+k*x_2<=x_f and y_1+k*y_2<=y_f:
        pixels[x_1+k*x_2,y_2+k*y_2]=colour
        k+=1
else:
    if x_f==Empty:
        while y_1+k*y_2<=y_f:
           pixels[x_1+k*x_2,y_2+k*y_2]=colour
           k+=1
    else:
        while x_1+k*x_2<=x_f:
           pixels[x_1+k*x_2,y_2+k*y_2]=colour
           k+=1
```

The issue with that isn't that it throws up an error, but rather that the program I have to run my code on won't allow me to run this - it crashes and gives me a CPU error. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you.

**Edit~**
I am using a function colour_pixels(x_1,x_2...y_f) to take my input.

My error is: "IVLE console restarted: Communication lost"

When inputting value y_f is inputted as "Empty"

I have to be able to take cases where either x_f or y_f could be 'Empty' - apologies, I didn't explain that very well

Thank you - I will change '!=' to 'is not' now!

Comment: How you are taking the input, is it raw_input()?

Comment: What is your cpu error? What do you mean by `x_f` is empty? Did you initialize `x_f` and `y_f` as `None`?

Comment: Your `if x_f!=None:` block. It means that `x_f` is not `None`. Thus you should do the operations involving `x_f`, not `y_f`.

Comment: Tip: use `if x is not None` instead of `x != None`

Comment: Thank you all - I have added an edit to the bottom of the question responding to your comments (I didn't realise I could comment back until just now)

Comment: So you program on IVLE console... I recommend you do it on CPython...

Comment: I was using IDLE, unfortunately I'm required to run it on IVLE in the end anyway, so I have to get it to work here. But thank you for your feedback - I'll definitely keep that in mind for next time I write anything

Comment: @KittiCat You shall be sure what version of Python you use, this shall prevent rather funny statements "I think 2.7" sounding like "I think, I am Kitty". The version is printed when starting python console, can be checked on command line `$ python -V`, or by `$ python -c "import sys; print sys.version"`, or in your code by `import sys` followed by `sys.version`. Good luck with narrowing unpredictable stuff around us :-)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - I've currently been alternating between two versions, and was not familiar with what IVLE was using (I know what the other program on my computer uses). I didn't know how to get the version like that though so thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should initialize `x_f` and `y_f` as `None`.

There are four cases: (`x_f` is `None` or not) x (`y_f` is `None` or not), and your code is missing the cases where both `x_f` and `y_f` are `None`. Also, your `if x_f!=None:` statement means that `x_f` is not `None`. Thus you should have the operation that involves `x_f`, not `y_f` in this block.

I think your code will be more readable if you create if-else statement like below:

```
if x_f==None:
    if y_f==None:
        ....
    else:
        ....
else:
    if y_f==None:
        ....
    else:
        ....
```

Comment: Sorry! I should have added - there isn't able to be a case where both x_f and y_f are None

Answer (score 0):

As I read this the section where you assign the colour is always the same, you just need to handle x_f or y_f (but not both) being Empty, which you can do in one conditional expression if you don't mind it being a bit verbose:

```
# For safety I would add an assert that at least one is not Empty
assert x_f is not Empty or y_f is not Empty
while (x_f is Empty or (x_1+k*x_2<=x_f)) and (y_f is Empty or (y_1+k*y_2<=y_f)):
    pixels[x_1+k*x_2,y_2+k*y_2]=colour
    k+=1
```

Comment: Thanks! That's an amazing way of simplifying what I want - I didn't know you could add the bracket-ed parts like that! IVLE still is refusing to run it though - do you have any idea why?

Comment: No idea, sorry. There is some info on that kind of error message here but it doesn't look promising: http://ivle.googlecode.com/svn/doc/sphinx/man/faq.html#the-console-return-console-restart-messages

I would try isolating exactly which part of the code is causing that error by cutting parts out, for example it may be the colour_pixels() function you mention that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks heaps - I managed to fix the error after speaking with a few people and explicitly running through my code and changing a few things around (eg. the input values that the functions were using, as one particular input created an infinite loop, causing the main problem). I completely missed it, but thanks heaps for your help!!!!